# Can non-druids shapeshift?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, wild-shape

I know that druids can use wild form to shapeshift into animals with wild form, but is there a way for others to shapeshift too, without multi-classing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes

The spells *polymorph*, *true polymorph* and *shapechange* allow you to take on another form. The Monster Manual also has rules for player-infliced lycanthropy, which can cause a transformation.

Comment: I think it's important to note that the spells do not make you a "shapeshifter," whereas lycanthropy does. This distinction makes a difference for a handful of spells.

Comment: Important to note that some of these options change your mental stats, so don't expect to change into a bear with Polymorph and execute complex tactical maneuvers.

Answer (score 6):

The Polymorph spell can allow it:

> Polymorph
>
> This spell transforms a creature with at least 1 hit point that you can see within range into a new form. An unwilling creature must make a Wisdom saving throw to avoid the effect. A shapechanger automatically succeeds on this saving throw.

I don't see why this could not be used on yourself, to allow you to change.

This means that anyone that has access to this spell, can transform at will (provided they have the necessary components, spell slots etc.). Classes that *have* access to this spell in 5e are: Bard, Druid, Sorcerer, Wizard

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many ways, depending on what you consider to be "shapeshifting".

Along with the answers already given, there are changeling and shifter races who can alter their appearance and physique.

Different methods will carry different limitations, however, and I do not believe that the wild-shape feature *specifically* is not available to player characters without multi-classing at present. It's hard to prove a negative, though.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**

Many spells make it so Non-Druids can shapeshift. For example, polymorph, true polymorph, shapechange, and alter self can change your appearance. Most of these you can't get until about Lv. 5, so it might take a while.

There're also magical items and Outer Planes that can change your appearance. An example of a magic item is **The Axe Of Dwarvish Lords**. It slowly changes you to look like a Dwarf.

Then finally, my favorite out of all of them, Lycanthropy. There are 5 types; Werebears, Wereboars, Wererats, Weretigers, and Werewolfs. There are two ways to become a Lyncanthrope, both of your parents being one, or being bitten by one.